# Why might bind() sometimes give EADDRINUSE when other side connects?

Tags: c++, sockets, udp, bind

In my C++ application, I am using ::bind() for a UDP socket, but on rare occasions, after reconnection due to lost connection, I get errno EADDRINUSE, even after many retries.  The other side of the UDP connection which will receive the data reconnected fine and is waiting for select() to indicate there is something to read.

I presume this means the local port is in use.  If true, how might I be leaking the local port such that the other side connects to it fine?  The real issue here is that other side connected fine and is waiting but this side is stuck on EADDRINUSE.

--Edit--

Here is a code snippet showing that I am already doing SO_REUSEADDR on my TCP socket, not on this UDP socket for which I am having issue:

```
// According to "Linux Socket Programming by Example" p. 319, we must call
// setsockopt w/ SO_REUSEADDR option BEFORE calling bind.
// Make the address is reuseable so we don't get the nasty message.
int so_reuseaddr = 1; // Enabled.
int reuseAddrResult
  = ::setsockopt(getTCPSocket(), SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &so_reuseaddr,
                 sizeof(so_reuseaddr));
```

Here is my code to close the UDP socket when done:

```
void
disconnectUDP()
{
  if (::shutdown(getUDPSocket(), 2) < 0) {
    clog << "Warning: error during shutdown of data socket("
         << getUDPSocket() << "): " << strerror(errno) << '\n';
  }
  if (::close(getUDPSocket()) < 0 && !seenWarn) {
    clog << "Warning: error while closing data socket("
         << getUDPSocket() << "): " << strerror(errno) << '\n';

  }
}
```

Comment: An important note, UDP is connectionless, the `connect()` call, when used on a UDP socket merely sets a default destination to `send()` to (and the only address from which datagrams are received). This will most likely always succeed given a valid IP address.

Comment: I'd just like to make sure, your code explicitly closes, then creates and binds a new socket? or does it try to call `bind` on the same socket as it used before? some (simplified) code would probably clarify this

Comment: The fact that the other side connects implies that the old socket is still open.  Did you close() it?  What do you mean by "lost connection" with datagrams?

Comment: @goldilocks: Assuming he only uses `connect()` and doesn't send anything, the other side connecting means nothing (other than that the local IP stack is alive), as no packets are sent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In UDP there's no such thing as lost connection, because there's no connection. You can lose sent packets, that's all.

Don't reconnect, simply reuse the existing `fd`.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, that's normal.  You need to set the socket `SO_REUSEADDR` before you bind, eg on *nix:

```
int sock = socket(...);

int yes = 1;
setsockopt(sock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &yes, sizeof(yes));
```

If you have separate code that reconnects by creating a new socket, set it on that one too.  This is just to do with the default behaviour of the OS -- the port on a broken socket is kept defunct for a while.

*[EDIT] This shouldn't apply to UDP connections.  Maybe you should post the code you use to set up the socket.*

Comment: You need to set `SO_REUSEADDR` each and every time you bind, not just when you try to bind again (which won't work because the previous socket didn't use the option)

Comment: Actually... on second thought, since UDP is connectionless, there shouldn't be a reason for this to matter (given the scenario), UDP sockets don't have anything like TCP's `TIME_WAIT`. An actual fd leak is more likely.

Comment: Not if the socket needs to use a specific port/address another party can send messages to.  It's the specific port number that's at issue. I'm 99.9% positive this is what the problem is.

Comment: IIRC, there isn't such a waiting period for UDP, I may be wrong, but a short test with netcat didn't show such issues

Comment: Hmmph.  I thought TIME_WAIT was an IP issue, but you're right, it's just TCP.  Which makes the EADDRINUSE mysterious.

Comment: I've even seen the issue on a port number used by another process which has exited.  Note the code works as is 99% of the time, and only occasionally does it fail.